# Errors vs failures in JavaScript Jasmine framework

Tags: javascript, jasmine

When running a JavaScript automated test created using the Jasmine framework, is there a way to distinguish between errors and failures (similar to how JUnit works)?

I have a function that receives and multiplies two numbers, first I'm sending two actual numbers and after that I'm sending a string so the function will fail:

```
it('properly multiply two numbers', function () {
    result = Multiply(10, 5);
    expect(result).toEqual(50);
});

it('throw an error if a parameter is not a number', function () {
    result = Multiply(10, 'aaa'); // should this line generate an error or a failure?
    expect(result).toEqual(50);
});
```

When I run the tests, Jasmine report it as a failure, shouldn't it be an error instead?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails, because the error is unexpected.
Try the following:

`expect(function() { Multiply(10, 'aaa'); } ).toThrow("Error: not a number.");`

Comment: When I use that line I get this message: "The function throw an error if a parameter is not a number". Even if it's an error, it is reported as a failure, so,  seems like there is no division of concepts between failure and error like in JUnit, at least, not in how are they reported, right?

Comment: You need to add a period after the sentence, I didn't notice the period in the error. About your other question; a failure happens both when an unexpected error is thrown or an `expect` fails, so it is a bit different than JUnit. However, looking at the logging, you can quickly see why it fails.